# Web Project Shows Button Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am scratching my head on this debug error as it appears to me to be complaining the the `button1_click()` event does not exist, but I have it showing in my `C#` code behind.  This is the error that is presented:

> ASP.pages_addinformation_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'button1_Click' and no extension method 'button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.pages_addinformation_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And here is my **HTML** for the page

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="LightGray" style="height: 345px;">
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="abc" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="11" HeaderText="11" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="12" HeaderText="12" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("arcaca") %>' ID="arc" Visible="false"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("chk")) %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>     
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="Do Something" OnClick="button1_Click" />
</td>
```

And here is my **C#** for the page showing that the `button1_Click()` event is in the code behind

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Try clicking on that button in designer and see if it goes to that method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page code can't see it because it's `private`.  Make it `protected`:

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Essentially, under the hood, the "page" part of things *inherits* from the actual `Page` class that you build in the code-behind.  So in order to see anything from that parent class, those members need to be at least `protected` or above.

This is in contrast to, say, WinForms where the form code is all in the same class.